# Is there any way I can determine what specifically caused my computer to disconnect from the internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Recently, my computer has disconnected from the internet twice, while my other devices were completely unaffected. Is there any way I can determine, specifically from the error logs, or some other means, why my PC has disconnected itself from the internet?

Comment: It could be a hardware type of error in which case you might look in Reliability History (Control Panel , Security and Maintenance).  For software errors, look in event viewer.  See this article to help.   https://kb.iu.edu/d/bfvh#:~:text=Within%20Event%20Viewer%2C%20navigate%20to,up%20Networking%20Event%20IDs%20online.

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` should have at least **some** answers

Comment: @EugenRieck Not if the OP is using Windows...

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry, I didn't think of that. But randomly disconnecting Internet should have been a good clue.

Comment: I would suggest you could check if there is any clue in system Event log. Or I would suggest you download [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/zh-cn/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to collect logs to see which process initiated the issue. Otherwise, the more complex logs should be collected for further analysis.